# What is a good way to load an application specific font on Qt on Symbian?

Tags: qt, qt4, symbian

Is it possible to use QFontDatabase::addApplicationFont() in Symbian?
It seems to return -1 (error) even if the file exists?

If not, is there some alternative to this, apart from system-wide font installation?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I know that it's not the Qt way, but this can be realized with Symbian SDK like this:

```
TInt fontFileID;
TInt fontErr = CEikonEnv::Static()->ScreenDevice()->AddFile(
        _L("c:\\system\\apps\\<APPID>\\customFont.ttf"), 
        fontFileID);
```

[Here is](http://wiki.forum.nokia.com/index.php/TSS001192_-_Using_application-specific_custom_fonts) the full link. Hope it helps.

Comment: Depending on the font and how you use the font, you may have some problems in QT 4.6: http://bugreports.qt.nokia.com/browse/QTBUG-17506